# How to implement left to right swipe between screens

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have three pages:

1. A extends SherlockFragment
2. B extends SherlockFragmentActivity
3. C extends SherlockFragmentActivity

In A, on clicking a text I need to goto B and in B, on clicking a text I need to goto C. These are already done.

Now the requirement is, when I am at C and I swipe from left to right, I need to goto B. When I am at B and I swipe from left to right, I need to goto A.

How can I implement this? Is ViewPager enough for this functionality? I have doubt since A is a fragment and others are fragment activities.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about simpleGestureListner? you can simply use gesture to achieve what you want.

Comment: Why don't you convert B and C each into a `Fragment`?

Comment: @InnocentKiller ya will try with SimpleGestureListener and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through SimpleOnGestureListener it worked.

Code:

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        float sensitvity = 10;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
            //Swipe Left
        } else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
            //Swipe Right
        }

        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
};
```

In onCreateView add:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), simpleOnGestureListener);
```

Add below code where you define your view:

```
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
view.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class **SimpleGestureFilter.java**

```
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    public final static int SWIPE_UP = 1;
    public final static int SWIPE_DOWN = 2;
    public final static int SWIPE_LEFT = 3;
    public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

    public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
    public final static int MODE_SOLID = 1;
    public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC = 2;

    private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; // just an unlikely number
    private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
    private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
    private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

    private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC;
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean tapIndicator = false;

    private Activity context;
    private GestureDetector detector;
    private SimpleGestureListener listener;

    public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context, SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

        this.context = context;
        this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        this.listener = sgl;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!this.running)
            return;

        boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

            if (event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            else if (result)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            else if (this.tapIndicator) {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                this.tapIndicator = false;
            }

        }
        // else just do nothing, it's Transparent
    }

    public void setMode(int m) {
        this.mode = m;
    }

    public int getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean status) {
        this.running = status;
    }

    public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMaxDistance() {
        return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinDistance() {
        return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinVelocity() {
        return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
        final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

        if (xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance
                || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
            return false;

        velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

        if (velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity
                && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

            result = true;
        } else if (velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity
                && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
            if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        this.tapIndicator = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
        this.listener.onDoubleTap();
        ;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

        if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) { // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
            arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE); // action which will be converted to an
                                        // ACTION_UP later.
            this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
        }

        return false;
    }

    static interface SimpleGestureListener {
        void onSwipe(int direction);

        void onDoubleTap();
    }
}
```

and then in your fragmentActivity do it like this,

```
public class abcd extends .... implements SimpleGestureListener{

//declare this,
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

//assign this
detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

and then,

@Override
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
     // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
     this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
     return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
     }

     @Override
     public void onSwipe(int direction) {
     switch (direction) {

     case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
     Intent moreOption = new Intent(Login1.this, Home.class);
     startActivity(moreOption);
     break;
     case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
     break;
     case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN:
     break;
     case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP:
     break;
     }
     }

     @Override
     public void onDoubleTap() {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't swipe between Activities. You can swipe between Fragments. 
For Achieve this. You should have one SherlockFragmentActivity as MainActivity,
And You need to create Three Fragments A, B, C which extends SherlockFragment.

For More details about how to do it, refer this [link](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-actionbar-tabs-with-swipeable.html#.UzKx8vmSxOo)